# Back-add integers in pandas dataframe based index from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames and would like to produce a result based on the following:

*DataFrame 1 has float number and it doesn't matter what the values are in the second DataFrame. 
Both DataFrames have the same number of columns, but df1 has a few extra rows because it has more entries in its index, spread out throughout the index.

**Question**

How can I get a DataFrame of the shape of df2 but with the values of df1 with the constraint that if there is a df1 value at an index that is not in df2, the df1 value must be added to the previous valid index (i.e. non-NaN) in that column in df2. res_df shows the result derived from df1 and df2.*

**DataFrame 1**

```
import pandas as pd

df1_col1 = pd.Series([2.5, .5, 1, 1, .5, .5, 2], index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
df1_col2 = pd.Series([2, 2, 2, 1, 1], index=[0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0])
df1 = pd.concat([df1_col1, df1_col2], axis=1)

>>> df1
       0   1
0.0  2.5   2
2.0  NaN   2
2.5  0.5 NaN
3.0  1.0 NaN
4.0  1.0   2
5.0  0.5 NaN
5.5  0.5 NaN
6.0  2.0   1
7.0  NaN   1
```

**DataFrame 2**

```
df2_col1 = pd.Series(['val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val'], index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
df2_col2 = pd.Series(['val', 'val', 'val', 'val'], index=[0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 7.0])
df2 = pd.concat([df2_col1, df2_col2], axis=1)

>>> df2
       0    1
0.0  val  val
2.0  NaN  val
2.5  val  NaN
3.0  val  NaN
5.0  val  NaN
5.5  val  NaN
6.0  val  val
7.0  NaN  val
```

**Expected Result**

```
res_col1 = pd.Series([2.5, .5, 2, .5, .5, 2], index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
res_col2 = pd.Series([2, 4, 1, 1], index=[0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 7.0])
res_df = pd.concat([res_col1, res_col2], axis=1)

>>> res_df
       0   1
0.0  2.5   2
2.0  NaN   4
2.5  0.5 NaN
3.0  2.0 NaN
5.0  0.5 NaN
5.5  0.5 NaN
6.0  2.0   1
7.0  NaN   1
```

I'm using pandas 0.18.0 on Linux Ubuntu and the solution needs to work for python 2.7.6 and python 3.5.1. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a clearer example of the catch you refer to.

Comment: The difference between df1 and df2 is that there are no values at index 4.0 in df2 so in res_df the values at that index from df1 get added to the previous valid indecies in their respective columns.

Comment: What if there is no "previous valid index"? Should the value be discarded? Or is it safe to assume it doesn't happen?

Comment: @ptrj in this case it is safe to assume there will always be a previous valid index if there is a value in df1 at an index where there isn't one in df2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Track what's missing, we'll loop over these
isin = df1.index.isin(df2.index)
missidx = df1.index[~isin]

# Base case in preparation for back-add
res_df = df1.reindex_like(df2)

# For each missing index
for i in missidx:
    # iterate over df2 columns
    # because we need to capture
    # its last valid index prior
    # the missing index we've found
    for j, col in df2.iteritems():
        # look for last valid index prior to i
        lvi = col.loc[:i].last_valid_index()
        # take value in df1 (now in res_df)
        # at last valid index from df2
        # and add to it the value in df1
        # at the missing index i
        res_df.at[lvi, j] += df1.at[i, j]
```

[image]

#### Pretty function

```
def pir_back_add(df1, df2):
    isin = df1.index.isin(df2.index)
    missidx = df1.index[~isin]

    res_df = df1.reindex_like(df2)

    for i in missidx:
        for j, col in df2.iteritems():
            lvi = col.loc[:i].last_valid_index()
            res_df.at[lvi, j] += df1.at[i, j]

    return res_df
```

---

#### Timing

My solution has beat out all others by a large margin.

```
piRSquared
1000 loops, best of 3: 677 µs per loop
```

---

```
Kartik
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop
```

---

```
ptrj
100 loops, best of 3: 4.55 ms per loop
```

---

```
Alberto Garcia-Raboso
100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop
```

---

```
Alex
100 loops, best of 3: 2.28 ms per loop
```

Comment: This makes it the right shape but doesn't do the back-adding. The value at index 3.0 in column 0 and the value at index 2.0 in column 1 are wrong.

Comment: @Alex Updated my post.

Comment: Thanks, this may have to be adjusted to be run on each column separately but it looks great. Congrats on the bounty.

Comment: Nice code. BTW, how large your testing data was? Performance depends very much on it. If `missidx` is relatively large then calls to `loc` and `last_valid_index` become costly and vectorized solutions may run much faster. You may try with, say, `df1` with 10000 rows and `missidx` of size 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about my other answer, I realized that there is a much better way of handling this problem. You still want to use `pd.cut()` to create bins for `df1.index`, but you want to create them separately for each column — using both `df2.index` and the indices of those rows of `df1` that do not have `NaN` in the column. Here's the code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd

df1_col1 = pd.Series([2.5, .5, 1, 1, .5, .5, 2],
                     index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
df1_col2 = pd.Series([2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
                     index=[0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0])
df1 = pd.concat([df1_col1, df1_col2], axis=1)

df2_col1 = pd.Series(['val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val'],
                     index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
df2_col2 = pd.Series(['val', 'val', 'val', 'val'],
                     index=[0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 7.0])
df2 = pd.concat([df2_col1, df2_col2], axis=1)

res_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.index)
for col, values in df1.iteritems():
    bin_bdrys = list(df1[col].dropna().index.intersection(df2.index))
    bin_bdrys.append(df2.index[-1] + 1)
    bins = pd.cut(df1.index, bin_bdrys, right=False, labels=bin_bdrys[:-1])
    res_df[col] = df1[col].groupby(bins).sum().reindex_like(df2)
print(res_df)
```

Output:

```
       0    1
0.0  2.5  2.0
2.0  NaN  4.0
2.5  0.5  NaN
3.0  2.0  NaN
5.0  0.5  NaN
5.5  0.5  NaN
6.0  2.0  1.0
7.0  NaN  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an elegant way to do it in this setting. An idiomatic and elegant solution is more likely to be possible on some stage before `df1` is created.

Here, it seems the only way is to iterate over columns of `df1`. Your solution is quite fast if there are relatively few extra elements in `df1.index`. If `df1.index.difference(df2.index)` is large, then the following trick with grouping may be useful:

Say, `s1` and `s2` are columns of, resp., `df1` and `df2`:

```
s1 = pd.Series(list(range(7)), index=[1.0, 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0])
s2 = pd.Series([1], index=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
s1
Out[198]: 
1.0    0
1.5    1
1.6    2
2.0    3
3.0    4
3.5    5
4.0    6
dtype: int64
```

Create a temporary series `s` to group by. The values of `s` are the valid `s2` indexes for all `s1` entries.

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan], index=s1.index)
s[s2.index] = s2.index
s = s.fillna(method='ffill')

s
Out[202]: 
1.0    1.0
1.5    1.0
1.6    1.0
2.0    2.0
3.0    3.0
3.5    3.0
4.0    4.0
dtype: float64
```

And the trick works as follows (note the resulting index is `s2.index`):

```
s1.groupby(s).sum()
Out[1203]: 
1.0    3
2.0    3
3.0    9
4.0    6
dtype: int64
```

### The whole code

Some care must be taken with `nan`'s. I infer from the description and your solution that `nan`'s locations in `df1` and `df2` are basically the same. If not, the code may need some modifications.

I also assume that the indexes of `df1` and `df2` are **monotonic** and contain **unique** values.

```
# Filling nan's that may interfere with the results
extra_idx = df1.index.difference(df2.index)
df1.loc[extra_idx] = df1.loc[extra_idx].fillna(0)
# If nan's in df1 and df2 coincide, the following would also work:
# df1 = df1.fillna(0)

result_cols = []
s = pd.Series(index=df1.index)

for col in df1.columns:
    c1 = df1[col]
    c2 = df2[col].dropna()

    s[:] = np.NaN
    s[c2.index] = c2.index
    s = s.fillna(method='ffill')

    out_col = c1.groupby(s).sum()
    result_cols.append(out_col)

result = pd.concat(result_cols, axis=1)
```

With `df1` and `df2` of shapes (10000, 10) and (7000, 10), this is almost 100 times faster than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a work-around, but I solved this problem with the following function:

```
def back_add(df1, df2):
    cols1 = [df1.iloc[:, x].dropna() for x in range(len(df1.columns))]
    cols2 = [df2.iloc[:, x].dropna() for x in range(len(df2.columns))]

    for i, ser in enumerate(cols1):
        for j, val in enumerate(ser):
            if ser.index[j] not in cols2[i].index:
                ser.at[ser.iloc[:j].last_valid_index()] += val
                ser.iat[j] = float('nan')
        ser = ser.dropna()
    return pandas.concat(cols1, axis=1).dropna(how='all')
```

It really seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.cut()` lets you use `df2.index` to create intervals for `df1.index`. Then you can `groupby` those intervals and sum.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1_col1 = pd.Series([2.5, .5, 1, 1, .5, .5, 2],
                     index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
df1_col2 = pd.Series([2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
                     index=[0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0])
df1 = pd.concat([df1_col1, df1_col2], axis=1)

df2_col1 = pd.Series(['val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val'],
                     index=[0.0, 2.5, 3.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6])
df2_col2 = pd.Series(['val', 'val', 'val', 'val'],
                     index=[0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 7.0])
df2 = pd.concat([df2_col1, df2_col2], axis=1)

bin_bdrys = list(df2.index)
bin_bdrys.append(df2.index[-1] + 1)
bins = pd.cut(df1.index, bin_bdrys, right=False, labels=df2.index)

res_df = df1.groupby(bins).sum()
```

This almost gets what you want:

```
print(res_df)

#        0    1
# 0.0  2.5  2.0
# 2.0  NaN  2.0
# 2.5  0.5  NaN
# 3.0  2.0  2.0
# 5.0  0.5  NaN
# 5.5  0.5  NaN
# 6.0  2.0  1.0
# 7.0  NaN  1.0
```

The problem is that `df1.loc[4.0, 1]` got added to `res_df.loc[3.0, 1]`. But `df1.loc[3.0, 1]` was `NaN`… You can easily identify where this happens:

```
incorrect = (res_df.notnull() & df1.isnull()).dropna()
print(incorrect)

#          0      1
# 0.0  False  False
# 2.0  False  False
# 2.5  False  False
# 3.0  False   True
# 5.0  False  False
# 5.5  False  False
# 6.0  False  False
# 7.0  False  False
```

Now let's rectify it:

```
# Iterate over columns
for col, values in incorrect.iteritems():
    # Get the indices of the entries that are wrong
    old_idx = values.nonzero()[0]
    # Get the valid indices
    valid_idx = df1[col].notnull().nonzero()[0]
    # Get the previous valid index for each wrong entry
    new_idx = np.searchsorted(valid_idx, old_idx) - 1
    # Add the wrong entry to the correct position, and `NaN` the former
    for i, j in zip(old_idx, new_idx):
        res_df.iloc[j, col] += res_df.iloc[i, col]
        res_df.iloc[i, col] = np.nan

print(res_df)

#        0    1
# 0.0  2.5  2.0
# 2.0  NaN  4.0
# 2.5  0.5  NaN
# 3.0  2.0  NaN
# 5.0  0.5  NaN
# 5.5  0.5  NaN
# 6.0  2.0  1.0
# 7.0  NaN  1.0
```

It is instructive to see the values of the different variables in the `for` loop above. There are no mistakes in the first column, so

```
old_idx = []
valid_idx = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_idx = []
```

(You could add an `if` statement to avoid looping over this column). For the second column, we get

```
old_idx = [3]
valid_idx = [0, 1, 4, 7, 8]
new_idx = [1]
```

So `res_df.iloc[3, 1]` is added to `res_df.iloc[1, 1]`, and `res_df.iloc[3, 1]` is reset to `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
# Step 1: Merge df1 and df2 on df2 (to make the shape the same):
df_merge = df2.join(df1, lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')

# Step 2: Bit of indexing elbow grease:
for col in df2.columns:
    non_nan = df_merge[str(col)+'_x'].notnull()
    df_merge.loc[non_nan,str(col)+'_x'] = df_merge.loc[non_nan,str(col)+'_y']

# Step 3: Drop the columns from df1:
df1_cols = [str(col)+'_x' for col in df1.columns]
df_merge.drop(df1_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
df_merge.columns = df2.columns
```

Does this solve all your use cases?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but it doesn't seem to work for `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]}, index=[0, 1])` and `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]}, index=[0]})`.